# Angular still performs property checking if *ngIf is false

Tags: html, angular, typescript, interface

I am using a variable in my Angular project that is defined as following:
`item: Interface1|Interface2`. Both interfaces have the property "section", but it is defined differently as following.

Interface1:

```
section: string;
```

Interface2:

```
section: {
   property1: string;
   property2: string;
};
```

Now when I am rendering, I am calling the following code:

```
<h2 *ngIf="check">
   {{ item.section.property1}
</h2>
<h2 *ngIf="!check">
   {{ item.section}
</h2>
```

check is true when the element is of the type Interface2 and should therefore act as a guard from my understanding. I thought since the first heading should not be rendered, it shouldn't matter that item does not have property1 in that case. I get an error though, that says "Property 'property1' does not exist on type 'string'".

What am I doing wrong?

I have tried putting the *ngIf in an ng-template around the heading, since from my understanding it shouldn't be added to the DOM then, but that resulted in the same error.
I then tried defining the item as followed: `item: Interface1&Interface2`, which removed the error, but when trying to render the second heading, it displayed [object Object] instead of the string.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it now, what worked in the end was defining item as:

```
item: Interface1&Interface2
```

I had another bug in my code that was causing the [object Object] error.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do `Interface1 & Interface2`, you should do `Interface1 | Interface2`.

Check another time how you define your `check` variable because I see that your prolem is on different behavior.

I tried to reproduce your case so here is code: https://angular-b2pk9z.stackblitz.io

Comment: I can't seem to get the source code for your stackblitz, do you have it set on locked? Either way, I have checked the value of "check" in ngOnInit() and it is correct and I have also replaced it with a type check and it didn't work either. I get the error even before i enter the page that should display my value, so maybe it is some problem with angular configuration?

Comment: @Alexandra, You may have a very strict configuration enabled in tsconfig.json